# Overload resolution of function dependent on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

In the example below, a function template (`quartic`) uses an overloaded global function (`square`). When compiled, only overloads that are declared before the template itself are considered, so `square(int)` is used rather than `square(double)`, even though `square(double)` is declared before the template is used.

```cpp
int square(int);

template<typename T>
T quartic(T value) {
    return square(square(value));
}

double square(double);

double x(double y) {
    return quartic(4.0); // Uses square(int), wanted square(double)
}
```

Is there a way to make the resolution of which overloaded version of `square` depend on what is available when the template is used, so that the user can implement `square` for any type `T` he uses?

Note: Oddly MSVC will use `square(double)`, while GCC, clang and icc uses `square(int)`.

Comment: can you add the main function please?

Comment: @yaodav the example is complete (try https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n7bcqr).

Comment: Only functions declared before `quartic` is supposed to be considered. I find it strange that MSVC uses the `double` version.

Comment: @TedLyngmo by default, MSVC always looks up at the time the template is instantiated, which is different from what standard asks. but it can be disabled by a compile flag.

Comment: ... that flag being `/permissive-`. Use that to get MSVC to be more correct in several ways.

Answer (score 5):

the `square` in function template `quartic` is a ***dependent name***, which means it depends on the template argument `T` and its lookup is postponed until `T` is known. besides, it's an ***unqualified name*** (a *qualified name* looks like `std::cout`), which means it will be looked up in not only its namespace but *the namespace of the arguments*, which is called ***argument-dependent lookup***, ***ADL***.

so in this case:

- ***non-ADL lookup*** examines function declarations with external linkage that are visible from the ***template definition context***. (the reason is explained in [[1]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name))
- ***ADL*** examines function declarations with external linkage that are visible from either the ***template definition context*** or the ***template instantiation context***.

obviously, it's not permitted to let your example work by *non-ADL lookup*. and neither do *ADL*, because `double` is not considered by *ADL*.

but if the arguments are user-defined type, it works by *ADL*. more clearly, if you want to call a function defined behind the this scope, you can make that function ***visible through ADL***, which means the function and the arguments' type (or indirect type, see [[2]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)) are in the same namespace.

references:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Answer (score 1):

Only functions declared before `quartic` are supposed to be considered, so MSVC does the wrong thing. One possible way to get around this would be to make `square` a function template too and let users provide specializations for it.

Your code:

```
template<typename T> T square(T);

template<typename T>
T quartic(T value) {
    return square(square(value));
}
```

User code:

```
template<> int square(int value) {
    return value * value;
}

template<> double square(double value) {
    return value * value;
}
```